# reference type conversion in template function?

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <iostream>
const char* max(const char* a, const char* b) {
    return strcmp(a,b) < 0 ? b : a;
}

template <typename T>
const T& max(const T& a, const T& b, const T& c) 
{
    return max(max(a,b),c);
}

int main()
{
    char* a = "abc";
    char* b = "cde";
    char* c = "def";
    const char* r = max(a,b);
    char* s = max(a,b,c);
    return 0;
}
```

cannot compile:

> max3a.cpp:9:12: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to
>   'char*' [-fpermissive]
>
> ```
> return max(max(a,b),c);
> ```

If I change the template function to

```
template <typename T>
const T& max(const T& a, const T& b, const T& c) 
{
    (const T)return max(max(a,b),c);
}
```

then it compiles successfully.

If `T` is `char *`, the type of `max(max(a,b),c)` is `const char*`, which is `const T`. Why?

Comment: Because you define it. You could remove `const` from line 2.

Comment: You probably want a overload for `char *max(char*, char*)`.

Comment: `char* a = "abc";` is invalid C++, it should be `const char* a = "abc";`

Comment: Adding a log on to that fire, you're returning a reference to a local temporary in your template function. Even if you fix the pointers in `main()`, it's not clear you intended to do *that*.

Comment: With proper compiler flags, I can't compile even the 2nd code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `T` is `char *` (pointer to char), then the return type of `max<T>()` is **not** `char const *` (pointer to constant char).

It is `char *const&` (reference to a *constant pointer* to char).

You get an error because you can't implicitly convert a *pointer to constant char* into a *pointer to mutable char*.

Comment: the key is `const T` does equal to `const char*`

Comment: @Jichao, no it's not.  If `T` is `char *` (a **pointer to `char`**), then `const T` is a **constant pointer to `char`** (`char *const `), NOT a **pointer to constart `char`)** (`char const *`).  It may help your understand to consistently write the `const` at the latest position it can appear (i.e. write `T const` rather than `const T`) to avoid this common confusion.